# Foreign key with composite primary key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship, composite-key

I would like to relationship but I don´t know how to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE One(
    Url char(100),
    Name char(25),
    Server char(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(Url,Name) );

CREATE TABLE Two(
    Name char(25),
    Url char(25),
    Name char(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(Name) );
```

The **Table Two** FOREIGN KEY is 'Url' and 'Name' (to **Table One** 'Url' and 'Name').

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply do this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (Name, Url)  
      REFERENCES One(Name, Url)
```

Keep in mind though that your table `Two` has two columns with the name `Name`, and `Url` has a different length in `One` (100) and in `Two` (25). So you need to change that.

Comment: This option doesn´t wok because the message that Mysql console show me is this: Erro 1215 (HY000)  Impossible dájouter des contraintes d'index externe.
Note: I modified the columns with teh right length